# Turn two ODEs first degree into a Hamiltonian with code

Tags: algorithms, python, hamilton-equations, canonical-transformation

This is more like a coding question, but I thought I'll post it here because of its mathematical foundation.

Two ODEs first degree can describe a Hamiltonian System. The connection between the ODEs and the Hamiltonian System is given by the canonical equations which are:

$
\dot{x}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}
$

$
\dot{y}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}
$

For example:

Two ODEs:

$
\dot{x}= 2y
$

$
\dot{y}= -2x
$

Results in the following Hamiltonian:

$
H(x,y)=x^2+y^2
$

Is there a way to create a code/algorithm, that can calculate the Hamiltonian from these ODE?

Comment: Isn't there a typo? Was expecting $\dot x = -\partial H/\partial x$

Comment: Look  up the book Numerical Recipes. Mentions important caveats for taking derivatives.  Also look up Runge Kutta 4 for integrations. That should get you doing numerical calculus.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed you're right I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the differential equations
$$ \eqalign{\dot{x} &= f(x,y)\cr
  \dot{y} &= g(x,y)\cr} $$
you want $H= H(x,y)$ such that $$\eqalign{\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} &= -g(x,y)\cr
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} &= f(x,y)\cr} $$
That is, $H$ is a scalar potential for the vector field $\langle -g(x,y), f(x,y) \rangle$.  Of course you need this vector field to be conservative.  If this is the case, first take an antiderivative of the first component with respect to $x$:
$$ V(x,y) = \int -g(x,y)\; dx$$
Then we should have $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (H - V) = 0$, so $H - V$ should be a function of $y$ alone.
And $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} (H - V) = f(x,y) - \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}$$ so
$$ H - V = \int \left(f(x,y) - \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \right) \; dy + constant$$
i.e. a Hamiltonian is $$H = V + \int \left( f(x,y) - \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \right)\; dy $$

Answer (score 0):

You prob want a subroutine that can take a function as an argument. You might also want a variable step size.

If step size is $\Delta x>0, dy/dx=f(x,y)$ then $y_{i+1}\approx y_i + \Delta x f(x,y), x_{n+1}=x_n + \Delta x$. Then iterate.

That's not the most stable or accurate way of performing an integration. RK4 is much better in both regards.

As to taking derivatives, $df/dx \approx \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$. You can just use the definition and use a small step size. Too big, obviously the calculation isn't accurately approximating, too small a step size, you could get a similar problem.

To reduce that issue, you want to use the symmetric derivative. $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+\Delta x/2)-f(x-\Delta x/2)}{\Delta x}$. This will give you a fairly accurate approximation to the derivative. One caveat among possibly many, it will give you a derivative where the derivative does not exist, cf. $|x|$ at $x=0$.

As to your specific problem. $H=x^2+y^2\implies \partial H/\partial x =2x $ yet it is given that $\dot{x}=2y$. Was that a mistake?